# Is it a good practice to use locks for queuing tasks?

Tags: c#, locking

I need to put some requests that can arrive at any time in a queue, in a way that each task only starts when the previous one ends. The question is, is it a good idea to use locking for this purpose? Does it have any bad effects, and do the queuing behavior that I expect result from this?

To be more specific, consider the code:

```
private int MyTask() {
   ...
}

private object someLock = new object();

public Task<int> DoMyTask() {
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock (someLock)
        {
            return MyTask();
        }
    });
}

public void CallMyTask() {
    var result = await DoMyTask();
}
```

Note that `CallMyTask()` will be called at any time, possibly concurrently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it a good idea to use locking for this purpose? Does it have any bad effects, and do the queuing behavior that I expect result from this?

Locking is not a good solution here. The bad effects are that it blocks a thread pool thread *from the time the work is in the queue* until the time that work completes. So if your code queues up 1000 requests, it will call `Task.Run` 1000 times, and potentially use up that number of thread pool threads, each of which is doing nothing but waiting on the lock.

Also, locks aren't strictly FIFO. They're just mostly-sorta-FIFO. This is because strictly-FIFO locks cause other problems like lock convoys; [the links in this issue have some great discussion about lock "fairness" (i.e., FIFO behavior)](https://github.com/python-trio/trio/issues/54#issue-207482123).

So, I recommend an actual queue. You can use `ActionBlock<T>` from [TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) to act as a true queue. Since your requests have *results*, you can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` for the enqueuing code to be able to get the result. `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is an "asynchronous signal" - in this case, we're using it to notify the calling code that *their specific* request has passed through the queue and been executed.

```
private ActionBlock<TaskCompletionSource<int>> queue =
    new ActionBlock<TaskCompletionSource<int>>(tcs =>
    {
      try { tcs.TrySetResult(MyTask()); }
      catch (Exception ex) { tcs.TrySetException(ex); }
    });
```

Each time we send a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to this `queue`, it will run `MyTask()` and capture the results (whether successful or an exception), and will pass those results to the `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

We can then use it like this:

```
public Task<int> DoMyTask() {
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
  queue.Post(tcs);
  return tcs.Task;
}

public void CallMyTask() {
  var result = await DoMyTask();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think locking is pretty much the only way to achieve this yourself, but the .NET framework should be able to do this for you if you use a [blocking collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and a [concurrent queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). The Blocking collection gives you an implementation of the producer/consumer pattern that is thread safe.

Here is an example which will print numbers in order.

```
class Program
{
    private static BlockingCollection<Task> m_BlockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<Task>(new ConcurrentQueue<Task>());
    private static int Counter;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(ProcessQueue); //Don't await for this demo!
        Task.Run(AddStuffToQueue); //Don't await for this demo!

        Console.ReadLine();
        m_BlockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
        while (!m_BlockingCollection.IsAddingCompleted)
            Thread.Sleep(5);
    }

    private static void AddStuffToQueue()
    {
        while(true)
            m_BlockingCollection.Add(new Task(() => Console.WriteLine(Interlocked.Increment(ref Counter))));
    }

    private static async Task ProcessQueue()
    {
        while (!m_BlockingCollection.IsCompleted && m_BlockingCollection.TryTake(out Task task))
            ProcessTask(task);
    }

    private static void ProcessTask(Task task)
    {
        task.RunSynchronously();
    }
}
```

This may not be a perfect example, but I'm sure you get the idea. The producer/consumer wraps the concurrent queue, so Tasks are performed as First in / First out (FIFO).

It is possible to have multiple consumers for the blocking collection, but if you want things processed one at a time, then having a single consumer as demonstrated should suffice.

I hope that helps!